# Add custom section on order create backend Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, backend

**I want to add custom section when admin order create..**

[image]

Comment: You want to added it programmatically or through Backend

Comment: explain please?!

Comment: create custom section like Shipping method

Comment: My question is clear you want to do it through the Backend or programmatically (coding way)

Comment: yes exactly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In **xml** File :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="data">
            <block type="module/adminhtml_sales_order_create_client" template="module/module.phtml" name="module" after="form_account" />  
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

> add **childHtml** block in phtml file

**app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\create\data.phtml**

```
<div id="order-form_account"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('module') ?></div>
```